# Периодически менять фоновое изображение

Tags: android

Есть разметка для активити корневой элемент `relativelayout`. Есть около 30 изображений, которые будут фоном для него. Я хочу чтобы при переходе в данный активити фон у `relativelayout` менялся периодически через 10 секунд. Как этого добиться? В какую сторону копать?

Answer (score 0):

```
public void onCreate() {
...
ImageView backgroundImageView = findViewById(R.id.background);
backgroundImageView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    static int i = 0;
    public void run() {
        ImageView.this.setImageResource(
            i++ % 2 == 0 ?
                R.drawable.background_image1 :
                R.drawable.background_image2);
        ImageView.this.postDelayed(this, 1000);
    }
}, 1000);
}
```